# Cant receive data from gitHub API

Tags: reactjs, github, github-api

I try to receive data from gitHub API. As the name is entered in input element I send a request to

[https://api.github.com/search/users?q=${username}](https://api.github.com/search/users?q=$%7Busername%7D) in:login type:user.

And I`m expecting that I received all users with this username (input element may has whole username or just a part of username). But got only one user.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `async and await` method to get your proper result.

```js
const gitUsers = async (username) => {
  const response = await fetch(`https://api.github.com/search/users?q=${username}`);
  const result = await response.json();
  console.log(result);
};

gitUsers("carl")
```